# Keeping Excel always in full screen mode

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following code to make excel look like an "application" or web page when it starts, to make it full screen:

```
With ActiveWindow
.DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = False
.DisplayVerticalScrollBar = False
.DisplayHeadings = False
End With

Application.CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar.Enabled = False
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Application.CommandBars("Full Screen").Enabled = False
```

There is a way to prevent excel to return to "normal" mode? Since pressing the "esc" key does it.

Comment: Use an **OnKey** macro to trap the entry of the **Esc** key.

Comment: `Application.OnKey "{ESC}", "yourmacro"` where `yourmacro` does what you want when escape is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help :

```
' Disable the Esc key.
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.OnKey "{ESC}", ""
End Sub

' Return the Esc key to normal.
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   Application.OnKey "{ESC}"
End Sub
```

Put the above in the "ThisWorkbook" section in the VBA editor.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the Esc key.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.OnKey "{ESC}", ""
End Sub
```

Return the Esc key to normal.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   Application.OnKey "{ESC}"
End Sub
```

When you minimize the window the icons reappear. you need to also disable minimize of the window.